# Execution order of AuthorizationFilterAttribute and ActionFilterAttribute in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following controller.

```
public class ExampleController : ODataController
{
    [AuthorizationFilterAttribute]
    [ActionFilterAttribute]
    public SingleResult<Example> Get()
    {
        // return SingleResult
    }
}
```

According to the [HTTP Message Lifecycle (PDF)](http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) the Authorization Filter should be executed first.

[image: HTTP Pipeline]

But the action filter is executed *before* the authorization filter. What could be wrong and what can I do to execute the authorization filter first?

**Note:** The `ODataController` does derive from `ApiController`.

**Note 2:** The execution order doesn't change when I register the `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` on a Method, Class or even Global.

Comment: WebAPI pipeline does not have proper stage markers like MVC does. So the order they are configured is the order of execution.

Comment: @cackharot Unfortunately the order in which the attributes are configured doesn't seem to influence the order of execution.

Comment: @Jos I have found the same\similar issue. If I just use the '/odata' parameter I see the same, however, it seems all calls that have additional parameters like '/odata/$metadata....' honor the attribute. I will guess it is do to the Controller does not need to be called for just /odata. I think the question becomes how do I protect the /odata call.